# Call a ajax function on the elselect drop down change

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am using [elSelect](http://www.cult-f.net/elselect/) with mootools to change the look and fell of a select box. My problem is how can i call an ajax function when select box value changes?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent('domready', function() {
        var mySelect = new elSelect( {container : 'someId'} );
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since elSelect changes the HTML structure to replace the dropdown, you can't use the `change` event set on the original dropdown. The documentation doesn't show any way to bind events to the replaced dropdown.

I'm not at all familiar with the way mootools works, but I notice in the source of the plugin that it has several event handlers defined, among which is `onOptionClick`. This gets triggered every time the user clicks an option in the dropdown. You can piggyback on top of it - change the code in that function to also trigger your ajax request.

Another option would be analyse the HTML structure of the injected elements - you can start from the id you give the constructor and look for `.option` elements inside it. You can them poll them for changes at fixed intervals (using `setInterval`) and send ajax requests when you see the value has changed. Or you can add click handlers to each option and take it from there.